# in C , UNIX. mysql related error msgs

Tags: c

after compiling. I got

```
/usr/ccs/bin/ld: Unsatisfied symbols:
   mysql_query (first referenced in test3.o) (code)
   mysql_close (first referenced in test3.o) (code)
   mysql_init (first referenced in test3.o) (code)
   mysql_num_fields (first referenced in test3.o) (code)
   mysql_free_Result (first referenced in test3.o) (code)
   mysql_real_connect (first referenced in test3.o) (code)
   mysql_store_result (first referenced in test3.o) (code)
   mysql_error (first referenced in test3.o) (code)
   mysql_fetch_row (first referenced in test3.o) (code)
```

messages..
can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code..

Comment: It's difficult to tell you what's wrong with your code without seeing your code.

Comment: can anyone tell me what the error message say??  :(

Comment: @paulsmith out of curiosity whats the complete command that you are using to compile?

Comment: @samy.vilar   cc test3.c -I/opt/mysql/include/mysql

Comment: Maybe it can help you http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html

Comment: @paulsmith I see, well like @Jack links you must also set the path to the shared object. `-L/path/to/_mysql.so`

Comment: @samy.vilar That only sets the linker library search path.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yep, your right the whole command would probably be something like this `gcc -o app -I/usr/include/mysql -g -pipe -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing original_source.c -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lz -lcrypt -lnsl -lm -L/usr/lib64 -lssl -lcrypto` assuming hes on a 64 bit machine ... he should just take a look at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-unix-connect-mysql-c-api-program.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't *link* with the library.

Depending on environment (IDE, command line, etc.) how you do that is different. If you build on the command line, add `-lmysql` to the end of the command line to link with the library. In an IDE it's usually somewhere in the project settings, probably in a section/tab called "Linker".